# Passing multiple params in react-router

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass multiple strings through a react router Link to my destination. In the destination I'm only getting the first string that I send and not the rest of the strings .

```
 <li className='left-nav-link' id='nav-section1'>
              <Link to={this.props.section1} params={{naturalPersonId: 1, firstName: "foo"}} className={this.props.navSelection==='nav-section1'?activeClass:''} 
                    activeClassName={activeClass}>{this.props.nav1}</Link>
            </li>
```

On the destination if I do console.log(this.props.params) I see : Object {naturalPersonId:1} as the output , there is no firstName in the output params.Why is this so, what am I missing?

Comment: show more code please

Comment: You already posted this question less than 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an old version but I don't recall a `params` property. Anyway, check the lastest [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link)

To get them on a *querystring*

```
<li className='left-nav-link' id='nav-section1'>
          <Link to={ path: this.props.section1,
                     query: {naturalPersonId: 1, firstName: "foo"} }  className={this.props.navSelection==='nav-section1'?activeClass:''} 
                activeClassName={activeClass}>{this.props.nav1}</Link>
        </li>
```

Alternatively create a matching `<Route>` and compose the `<Link>` manually. Please check the docs & source before throwing this kind of questions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <li className='left-nav-link' id='nav-section1'>
     <Link to={this.props.section1} 
           params={params: {naturalPersonId: 1, firstName: "foo"}} 
           className={this.props.navSelection==='nav-section1'?activeClass:''} 
           activeClassName={activeClass}>{this.props.nav1}</Link>
 </li>
```